# How to take a set of geohashes and determine which ones are neighbors?

Tags: latitude-longitude, geohash

I'm trying to figure out the optimal way to take a list of geohashes and return a sub-list that contains the geohashes [that are direct neighbors](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html) or have direct neighbors in common (aka - creating groups of contiguous geohashes).

The only way I can think to do this is by looping through the geohashes, getting neighbors and adding them to a new list. Something like the psudo code below:

```
startingGeoHashes = ["9qczj5t",
                     "9qczj5s", # directly west of the above
                     "9qczj5e", # directly west of the above
                     "9qczjhh" # not a direct neighbor
]
neighborGroup = [] #This would actually be a list of lists to acccomadate multiple distinct groups
foreach startingGeoHash in startingGeohashes
   if any of startingGeoHashes in getGeoHashNeighbors(startingGeoHash):
      add both to neighborGroups if they aren't already in there
```

ideally the code above would return two groups:

```
9qczj5s,9qczj5t,9qczj5e
and
9qczjhh
```

But I'm wondering if there is a set based approach that could return the subset of direct neighbors without looping through every record and getting the neighbors to compare to everything else in the list.

Is this possible?

Language is not important but I will be implementing this in go if that makes any difference.